Connecting these words might create a flood
Connect the numbers and the words below as appropriate. Each number connects to one verb, and each verb connects to one noun.

CSV version:
NUMBERS: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
VERBS: BOIL, GRIEF, NOTE, PEEL, RING, RIP, TOAST, WRAP
NOUNS: AIRMAN, ALTAR, ASSET, JANE, LINE, MOON, RUM, STEM


The connections are as follows:

 1. BOIL & ASSET
 2. GRIEF & ALTAR
 3. WRAP & STEM
 4. PEEL & MOON
 5. TOAST & RUM
 6. RING & JANE
 7. RIP & AIRMAN
 8. NOTE & LINE

Why? Because...

 Each pair of words can be anagrammed together (hence the anagram tag) to form the name of a Pokémon (hence the video-games tag) from that particular number generation in the franchise. (For those not in the know, Pokémon games are released in numbered instalments. The instalment in which a particular Pokémon first appears is considered to be its 'generation'.)

 These are:

 Gen I: BOIL+ASSET=BLASTOISE
 Gen II: GRIEF+ALTAR=FERALIGATR
 Gen III: WRAP+STEM=SWAMPERT
 Gen IV: PEEL+MOON=EMPOLEON
 Gen V: TOAST+RUM=SAMUROTT
 Gen VI: RING+JANE=GRENINJA
 Gen VII: RIP+AIRMAN=PRIMARINA
 Gen VIII: NOTE+LINE=INTELEON

How does this explain the title?

 Fans of the games will spot the connection immediately - each of these Pokémon is a water type. Moreover, it is the final evolution of the water-type 'starter' Pokémon in that generation, i.e. the most powerful incarnation of the basic Pokémon you have a chance to select as your first 'catch' at the beginning of the game. These Pokémon will have high-powered moves that harness the power of water, potentially capable of 'creating a flood'!

How did I work this out?

 The anagram tag made me wonder if words from the verbs and nouns needed pairing up and anagramming together to form something recognisable, so I methodically paired 'BOIL' with each of the nouns until I chanced upon BOIL+ASSET. Realising this was an anagram of 'BLASTOISE' (on seeing the video-games tag, my mind immediately jumps to Pokémon out of force of habit, and I've been replaying Gen I with my daughter recently!), I started looking to see if I could spot any other Pokémon names formed similarly. On finding 'FERALIGATR' from GRIEF+ALTAR, I immediately realised I had two final-evolution water-type starter Pokémon from different games - a pattern, perhaps? So I checked the names of the others until I realised that each of the options from Gen I through VIII were represented!


One final observation: rot13(gur Tra VK jngre-glcr svany-ribyhgvba fgnegre Cbxézba vf DHNDHNINY - jvgu gjb D'f va gur zvk, creuncf vg'f ab jbaqre gur dhrfgvba frggre fgbccrq ng Tra IVVV vafgrnq bs nggrzcgvat gb vapyhqr guvf bar gbb!)
